# Cook PVI of New York Independent Redistricting Commission proposals?

Tags: united-states, new-york, redistricting

The New York State Independent Redistricting Commission has released congressional plans last September. [FiveThirtyEight](https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/redistricting-2022-maps/new-york/) has documented the partisan lean of each district today according to *its metrics* and the proposals put forward.

However, I wonder what the actual *Cook PVIs* of the districts are in both proposals. Cook PVI is roughly defined as a congressional district's voting relative to the nation in the last two presidential elections.

Note: this question is relevant because the state redistricting amendment failed which gives state Democrats little if any wiggle room to draw the maps the way they want.

Comment: The Cook PVI is a calculated value - there needs to be election data to determine it.  While not official, FiveThirtyEight's calculated value are going to be solid *prospective* values.  Unless you're comparing actual precinct or household voting records and mapping those, I would imagine 538's will be your best bet

Comment: The data is available

Comment: If you know the data is available, and where to get it (presumably), and you know all of this, then why not answer your question yourself, @NumberFile ?

Comment: Can you link said data, then?

Comment: You could find information at nyirc.gov

Comment: I went to nyirc.gov but didn't see any data so I guess I'm not answering this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data of the proposals can be downloaded from the New York State Independent Redistricting Commission's [website](https://nyirc.gov/draft-plans). This comes in the form of a mapping of census blocks to proposed districts. As electoral data is not directly available at the census block level, we need to find some way of mapping census blocks to precincts so that we can obtain the historical election data used to calculate each district's PVI.

Luckily, this mapping is available using a tool called Dave's Redistricting App. The two proposals, ["Names"](https://davesredistricting.org/maps#viewmap::9b4962de-5cbb-4b38-a0e8-9cadbaada9af) and ["Letters"](https://davesredistricting.org/maps#viewmap::ab8d0b73-fdea-4972-be15-8ecc2d23ca2a) can be viewed using this tool, and the PVIs of individual districts can be found by selecting the "President 2016/2020" election data source. This gives the following results:

| "Letters" Districts | PVI |  | "Names" Districts | PVI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | R+2.04 |  | ALBNYRNSLR | D+8.18 |
| B | D+7.38 |  | BUFFALO | D+7.71 |
| C | R+2.55 |  | CNTRKNGS | D+42.36 |
| D | D+14.09 |  | DCHSWSTCHSR | D+4.58 |
| E | D+31.11 |  | EASTNYFLTBSH | D+36.12 |
| F | D+36.15 |  | EASTQUEENS | D+16.2 |
| G | R+6.65 |  | EASTRIVER | D+33.22 |
| H | D+31.99 |  | EASTSUFLK | R+5.66 |
| I | D+39.35 |  | GLOW | R+10.88 |
| J | D+29.2 |  | JEFFRSNULSTR | R+11.29 |
| K | D+33.68 |  | JFK5TWNS | R+3.89 |
| L | D+33.42 |  | NORTHBRONX | D+33.67 |
| M | D+8.57 |  | NORTHEAST | R+5.31 |
| N | R+3.66 |  | NORTHMNHTN | D+38.45 |
| O | D+3.84 |  | NORTHNASSUF | D+1.87 |
| P | D+8.09 |  | QNSBLLMR | D+26.59 |
| Q | D+40.17 |  | ROCHESTER | D+7.58 |
| R | D+28.17 |  | SOUTHBRONX | D+37.83 |
| S | D+20.56 |  | SOUTHMNHTN | D+35.89 |
| T | D+6.43 |  | SOUTHNASSUF | R+5.65 |
| U | R+0.27 |  | STATENISLND | R+6.79 |
| V | R+11.12 |  | STHPENNBRDR | R+6.84 |
| W | R+3.39 |  | SULORNGRCK | R+2.49 |
| X | D+4.55 |  | SYRACUSE | D+0.78 |
| Y | R+8.94 |  | WESTQUEENS | D+18.64 |
| Z | R+13.71 |  | YONKERS | D+20.2 |